# Web Platform Installer Hadoop RE-install

Tags: hadoop, web-platform-installer, azure-hdinsight

I installed HDInsight (Hadoop) using the Web Platform Installer under Windows 8, only to find that the installer was set to install to IIS Express instead of IIS. So, I uninstalled it using Add/Remove Programs. Now I want to reinstall it to IIS, but when I run the Web Platform Installer, it thinks it is already installed and will not let me reinstall (the install button is disabled).

Is there a way to a) do a manual install of HPInsight, or b) force WPI to re-install.

BTW, I cleared the cache in WPI, thinking it might re-compute which features were installed, but it just deleted the installation files I could have used to manually install from the previously downloaded packages.

Answer (score 1):

better yet
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Search your registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for HDINSIGHT find the folder under the Products folder and DELETE the entire registry entry for that file ("Folder") that contain the HDINSIGHT entry under the ProductName string value. 
Took me a while to figure that one out.